# Is there a size limit for std::cin buffer?

Tags: c++

I want to get 300 numbers from the user and print out the largest number. First, I use this code to ask for input:

```
cout << "Enter the array\n";
```

Then I paste 300 number into the terminal and hit enter. Then use this code to capture the input:

```
int count = 300;
int inputArray[count];
for (int i = 0; i<count; ++i) {
    cin >> inputArray[i];
}
```

And the code doesn't work, it just asks for more and more numbers.

But when I paste in 150 numbers at a time, (for example, paste 1 to 150, hit enter, then paste 151 to 300, hit enter again) the code works just fine. So, I'm guessing there is a limit for the buffer on how many input it can handle. Am I right? How does std::cin works?

Side question: should I get the data from a file instead of using cin?

My full code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int count = 300;
    cout << "Enter the numbers\n";
    int inputArray[count];
    for (int i = 0; i<count; ++i) {
        cin >> inputArray[i];
    }
    cout << "Got input\n";
    int bigNum = inputArray[0];
    for (int i=1; i<count; ++i) {
        int in = inputArray[i];
        if (in > bigNum) {
            bigNum = in;
        }
    }
    cout << "The largest number is " << bigNum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The C++ standard does not require a maximum on the input buffer. Your operating system may impose its own limitations.

Comment: I'm using Xcode, should I looking for some settings in Xcode?

Comment: I would use the command line and pipe/redirect a file with your input in through your program.

Comment: Speaking as a user, if a program expected me to type in 300 entries in one shot, I would be looking for a different program.

Comment: haha, that's true

Comment: I think in this case the limitation is not in the OS but in the terminal emulation.

Comment: Take your input from a file instead of pasting so much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specified size limit on IO buffers that I could find in the standard, but there may be for your OS input buffer.